# conditional probability on zero probability events and conditional Radon-Nikodym derivatives

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider a stochastic process $\{x_t\}_{t\in T}$ adapted to some filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\{\mathcal{F}\}_{t\in T},\mathbb{P})$ taking values in the state space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$

I wish to consider the probability Pr$(x_t\in\mathcal{A}|x_s)$ where $(s<t)$

This *should* be a sensible question, as I should be able to assign probability to a question of the form "What is the chance I obtain an outcome $x_t \in [0.5,0.6]$ given that last time I got $x_s=0.4$". e.g. a transition probability.

Naturally we have Pr$(A| B)=$Pr$(A\cap B)/$Pr$(B)$ but then we have Pr$(B)=$Pr$(x_s)=0$ for any particular value.

Now I think that this is where we have the notion of regular conditional probability entering which, as I understand it means we write:

$$\text{Pr}(x_t\in \mathcal{A}|x_s=B)=\lim_{\mathcal{B}\to B}\frac{\text{Pr}(x_t\in \mathcal{A}\cap x_s \in \mathcal{B})}{\text{Pr}(x_s\in \mathcal{B})}$$

Vagaries of the meaning of $\lim_{\mathcal{B}\to B}$ aside (which would have to be implementation specific e.g. here $\lim_{r\to 0} \text{Pr}(x_s\in (B-r,B+r)$), **is the above correct?**

**Should I understand this as a Radon Nikodym derivative?** It seems related, but not identical.

**How do I relate this to, and formulate it in such a way to be consistent to, how conditional probabilities are usually defined?** (as I understand it) viz

$$\text{Pr}(x_t\in\mathcal{A}|x_s\in\mathcal{B})=\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}[1_{\mathcal{A}}(x_t)|\sigma(\mathcal{B})\subseteq\mathcal{F}_s]$$

Surely $$\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}[1_{\mathcal{A}}(x_t)|\sigma({B})]$$ just wouldn't work? i.e. $\sigma(B)\nsubseteq\mathcal{F}$?

**Is it legitimate to construct Radon-Nikodym derivatives out of measures formed from regular conditional probabilities?** i.e. is this (heuristically) ok?

$$\frac{d\mathbb{P}(x_t|x_s=B)}{d\mathbb{Q}(x_t|x_s=B)}=\lim_{\mathcal{A}\to\emptyset}\lim_{\mathcal{B}\to B}\frac{\mathbb{P}(x_t\in\mathcal{A}|x_s\in\mathcal{B})}{\mathbb{Q}(x_t\in\mathcal{A}|x_s\in\mathcal{B})}$$

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Based on discussion in the comments, the issues *appears* to boil down to why one can write

$$\text{Pr}(x_t\in \mathcal{A}|B)=\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}[1_{\mathcal{A}}(x_t)|\sigma({B})]$$

when $B$ is a zero probability event. What I don't understand is what the sigma algebra generated by a zero probability event looks like and why you can condition on it.

**Surely the sigma algebra generated by a zero probability event is itself formed from (complements and unions of) zero probability events in $\mathbb{P}$, thus not in $\mathcal{F}$**

e.g. $$\sigma(x_s=B)=\{\omega,\omega^c,\emptyset,\Omega\}\nsubseteq\mathcal{F}$$
with $\mathbb{P}(\omega)=0$ such that $\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}[f(x_t)|\sigma({B})]=\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}[f(x_t)]$ or $0$?

**so why can we condition on these?**

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: It seems the same question could be simplified to just considering a random vector $(X,Y)$, and defining $P[X \in A | Y=y]$, no?  The stochastic process and filtration stuff seems like a distraction from the main concepts here.

Comment: A non-measure theory version of probability might "define" this by flipping the conditioning, so $P[X\in A| Y=y] = \frac{f_{Y|X \in A}(y)P[X \in A]}{f_Y(y)}$, assuming $f_Y(y)\neq 0$ and $f_{Y|X \in A}(y)$ makes sense.

Comment: Ok, so I'm simplifying what I need this for (which ultimately is going to be random functions 'given' other functions), hence the desire for a proper measure theoretic understanding, but was hoping to streamline the discussion with the above. Granted you can do the above with probability densities.

Comment: If you are comfortable with expectations given sigma algebras, why not just use $P[X \in A|\sigma(Y)] = E[1_A(X)|\sigma(Y)]$?

Comment: Perhaps this is where my intuition breaks. Is conditioning on $\sigma(Y=y)$ legitimate and if so, as you suggest, why? I understand conditioning on $\sigma(\mathcal{Y})$ where $Y\in\mathcal{Y}$.

Comment: When I write $\sigma(Y)$, I mean "the sigma algebra generated by the random variable $Y$."  What do you mean by $\sigma(Y=y)$? Is it $\sigma(Y=y)=\{\{Y=y\}, \{Y\neq y\}, S, \phi\}$, i.e., a collection of 4 events? (where $S$ is the entire sample space and $\phi$ the empty set) (I also do not know what you mean by $\mathcal{Y}$ as opposed to $Y$)

Comment: I think you really want to condition on the sigma algebra generated by random variable $Y$, not the 4-event sigma algebra $\{\{Y=y\}, \{Y\neq y\}, S, \phi\}$.  Note that if $X$ is any random variable and $G$ is any event of prob 0, and if $\mathcal{H}=\{G, G^c, S, \phi\}$, then a version of $E[X|\mathcal{H}]$ is just $E[X]$ itself, i.e, it satisfies $\int_H E[X] dP = \int_H X dP$ for all $H \in \mathcal{H}$, since the integrals give either $0=0$ or $E[X]=E[X]$ for each of the four possibilities for $H$.

Comment: Ok, I will admit to being confused here. Yes, I am interpreting $\sigma(Y)$ as the sub sigma algebra in $\mathcal{F}$ generated by $Y$ on prob space $\Omega$? $\mathcal{Y}$ is supposed to be a (set of) events with non zero probability (such that it corresponds to events in $\mathcal{F}$ which in turn have non zero prob measure in $\mathbb{P}$). My understanding fails when considering $\sigma(Y=y)$ as I don't know what that it because Y=y has probability 0.

Comment: Agree with your last comment: that is exactly what I see happening for $E[X|\sigma(Y=y)]$ i.e. reducing to $E[X]$ which is not what I want. And hence why I am confused.

Comment: In other words, what is the sub sigma algebra generated by $Y=y$? Why are we allowed to condition on these events? Surely they are zero probability events too like in your comment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42914/discussion-between-user3353819-and-michael).

Answer (score 1):

Just a summary of my comments that may clarify: You "should never" consider the sigma algebra generated by an event (since it has *nothing to do* with expressions like $E[X|Y=y]$).  You "should" consider the sigma algebra generated by a random variable, and this has lots to do with expressions like $E[X|Y=y]$. Specifically...

Let $S$ be a sample space. Let $(X,Y)$ be a random vector that maps $S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$.   So $X(\omega)$ and $Y(\omega)$ are real numbers for all $\omega \in S$.

#### Useful:

$$\sigma(Y) = \mbox{Sigma algebra generated by random variable $Y$}$$

Then $\sigma(Y)$ has many events, including all events of the form $\{Y\leq y\}$ and $\{Y \in [y, y+\delta]\}$.  Now, $E[X|Y]$ (sometimes written $E[X|\sigma(Y)]$) is a random variable with certain properties. There are different "versions," but they all differ only on a set of measure 0.  Let $Z=E[X|Y]$ be a particular version.  It is "$Y$-measurable" and:

(i)  $Z(\omega) = f(Y(\omega))$ for some function $f$ and for all $\omega \in S$.

(ii) 
$ \int_H Z dP = \int_H X dP \quad \forall H \in \sigma(Y) $

Existence of such a thing can be proven using Radon-Nikodym concepts. 
Now, $E[X|Y=y]$ can be defined as the value $Z(\omega)$ for any value $\omega$ in which $Y(\omega) = y$.

#### Intuitive construction with $Z=E[X|Y]$.

Fix $\delta>0$ with $\delta \approx 0$.  Define $H = \{\omega : Y(\omega) \in [y, y+\delta]\}$. 
Suppose that $Z(\omega) \approx f(y)=E[X|Y=y]$ for almost all $\omega \in H$. Then: 
$$ \int_H X dP = \int_H Z dP \approx \int_H f(y) dP = f(y)P[Y\in [y, y+\delta]] $$
So: 
$$ f(y) \approx \frac{\int_{Y \in [y, y+\delta]} X dP}{P[Y \in [y, y+\delta]]} $$
and so we have an (unrigorous) property that: 
$$ f(y) = \lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\int_{Y \in [y, y+\delta]} X dP}{P[Y \in [y, y+\delta]]} $$
There might be some crazy examples where the limit does not exist or does not give the desired result.

#### Not useful:

$$\sigma(Y=y) = \{\{Y=y\}, \{Y\neq y\}, S, \phi\} $$

We can formally define $E[X|\sigma(Y=y)]$, *but this has nothing to do with $E[X|Y=y]$*.  It can be shown that, with prob 1, $E[X|\sigma(Y=y)]=E[X]$.  That is because, for any event $H \in \{\{Y=y\}, \{Y\neq y\}, S, \phi\}$ we have: 
\begin{align}
\int_H E[X] dP = E[X]\int_H dP = E[X]P[H] &= \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
E[X] &\mbox{ if $H=\{Y\neq y\}$ or $H=S$} \\
0  & \mbox{ otherwise} 
\end{array}
\right.\\
\int_H X dP &=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
E[X] &\mbox{ if $H=\{Y\neq y\}$ or $H=S$} \\
0  & \mbox{ otherwise} 
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. The only remaining question for me is what does $E[X|\sigma(Y)] (=E[X|(Y)])$ mean then/why is it written like that? Particularly when contrasted with the *very similar notation* in your 'not useful' section. If $E[X|\sigma(Y)]$ *doesn't* mean a function of the specific sigma algebra $\sigma(Y=y)$ as you might expect from that form from intro. prob. theory, might the '$|\sigma(Y)$' bit more loosely mean your eq (ii) is 'defined on/valid for domains in $\sigma(Y)$'? Such that it means 'given that you are integrating over a set that is in the (generic) sigma field of Y?'

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment.  In the "useful" case, equation (ii) holds for all sets $H$ in the infinite-collection $\sigma(Y)$.  In the "not useful" case, equation (ii) holds for all sets $H$ in the 4-element collection $\sigma(Y=y)$, that is, in the collection $\{\{Y=y\}, \{Y\neq y\}, S, \phi\}$. Considering the infinite number of sets in $\sigma(Y)$ allows you to perform your thought experiment of "shrinking" positive probability sets $B_{\delta}$ down to the zero-probability set $\{Y=y\}$, whereas this limiting intuition is impossible for the 4-element set $\sigma(Y=y)$.

Comment: Another way to view $E[X|Y]$ is as a random variable that "begs" to be integrated, so $E[E[X|Y]] = E[X]$ holds.   Similarly, perhaps you can think of $E[X|Y=y]$ as something that is not quite formally defined on its own.  It is only defined in terms of the _full_  random variable $Y$ and over _all_ $y \in \mathbb{R}$,  and begs to be integrated so that  $E[X]=\int_y E[X|Y=y]f_Y(y)dy$ holds.